# What's lost during clone() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, clone

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <select id="selector">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="Management">Management</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="test" />
```

script without clone(),works all right:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('#container').find('select').each(function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        var value = $elem.val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

script with clone(),not work:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').find('select').each(function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        var value = $elem.val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: value can't be retrieved,u can try it .

Comment: select a non "--" first,the 1st sample will pop up with selected value

Comment: The second sample also popped out with the selected value. Whats wrong in it?

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is with firefox. In IE it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the issue but you should note that when you clone a **`<select>`** element its selected item will be ignored if it was selected by the user. To get around this you can simply apply the **`selected`** DOM property to whichever option was originally selected. E.g.

```
$('#test').click(function(){

    var selectMenus = $('#container').find('select');

    $('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').find('select').each(function(i) {

        /* See this: */
        $('option', this)[selectMenus[i].selectedIndex].selected = true;

        var $elem = $(this);
        var value = $elem.val();
        alert(value);

    });

});
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is a cross-browser issue but it certainly affects FF3.5.